# Write $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})/\mathbb{Z}(20,30)$ as a direct product of cyclic groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules

How does one use the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Modules over PID to show this? I've started based on something I read elsewhere, but I'm not sure it's right or where to go from here.

Pick generators $\overline{(1,0)}$ and $\overline{(0,1)}$. We have
\begin{align}
&20\overline{(1,0)} + 30\overline{(0,1)} = \overline{(0,0)}\\
&20[\overline{(1,0)}+\overline{(0,1)}]+10\overline{(0,1)} = \overline{(0,0)} \\
&20\overline{(1,1)} + 10\overline{(0,1)} = \overline{(0,0)}
\end{align}
Let $\overline{(1,1)}$ be a new generator. Can continue to write
\begin{align}
&10(2\overline{(1,1)} + \overline{(0,1)}) = \overline{(0,0)} \\
&10\overline{(2,3}) = \overline{(0,0)}
\end{align}
Use $\overline{(2,3)}$ as a second generator and create a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})/\mathbb{Z}(20,30)$ with $(a,b) \mapsto a\overline{(1,1)} + b\overline{(2,3)}$... what result am I looking to get?

Comment: You've essentially done it. You have found generators $u:=(1,1), v:=(2,3)$ of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\mathbb{Z}(2,3)$ is exactly $\mathbb{Z} (10v)$. So the quotient is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}_{10}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with:

Notice that $Tor((\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})/\mathbb{Z}(20,30)) = (\overline{(2,3)})$ the submodule generated by $\overline{(2,3)}$ which is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/10\Bbb{Z}$. Since $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})/\mathbb{Z}(20,30)$ is not all torsion, there is a $\Bbb{Z}$ component in the decomposition. Also, you can verify that the rank of the module is $1$. So $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})/\mathbb{Z}(20,30) \cong \Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}_{10}$